# Access file downloaded with Alamofire to downloadsdirectory with unknown filename

Tags: ios, swift, networking, download, alamofire

I have an app for iOS that uses metal to render obj files.  I am trying to add functionality for users to insert the url of an obj file online and render that.  I am using alamofire and am not sure how I will access the file once downloaded, since I won't know the file name.

```
let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .downloadsDirectory)

let modelUrl = URL(string: "https://drive.google.com/file/d/110KRnku3N_K_EIN-ZLYXK128zjMqxGLM/view?usp=sharing")

Alamofire.download(
    modelUrl!,
    method: .get,
    parameters: Parameters.init(),
    encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
    headers: nil,
    to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
        //progress closure
    }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
        //here you able to access the DefaultDownloadResponse
        //result closure
    })
let file = try? String(contentsOf: URL(string: (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.downloadsDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]))!)
```

I am also fairly certain my method for retrieving the file will not work, but i'm not sure how to search the documents directory for a specific file.
The files I have working are in the project as .obj files in xcode, and I simply use this.

```
let assetURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: modelName, withExtension: "obj")
```

Answer (score 0):

`Bundle.main` will not return files in `document directory`, it is use for the files you put in your main bundle (inside Xcode while development usually). You need to use `FileManager` to access files in `document directory`. You can use this function to search files in your document directory.

```
func getFilePathInDocuments(fileName:String) -> String {
    let path        = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let url         = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let filePath    = url.appendingPathComponent(fileName).path

    if (fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath)) {
        return filePath
    }else{
        return ""
    }
}
```

This is how you call it:

```
let foundPath = getFilePathInDocuments(fileName: "fileName.obj")
```

**Update**:

You can give a `fileName` to `Almofire` and you will receive the downloaded URL too from it.

```
let destinationPath: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0];
    let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("fileName")
    return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
}

Alamofire.download(url, to: destinationPath)
    .downloadProgress { progress in
    }
    .responseData { response in
}
```

To get downloaded document directory URL use `response.destinationURL`.

Comment: Yeah, I was using Bundle.main for files I put in the xcode project.  The `let file = try? String(contentsOf: URL(string: (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.downloadsDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]))!)` is what I was trying for the downloaded files.  I'll try this out and get back to you, thanks.

Comment: How can I get the name of the file that I'm downloading from Alamofire.download (or another Alamofire method?)

Comment: @GabeSpound Yes, but you need to give name first for better search operations. See updated answer.